# If I get question banned on StackOverflow, will I also get banned on AskUbuntu?

Tags: support, post-ban

I am on the verge of being banned from asking questions on Stack Overflow. I'm not sure why, I guess people don't really like my questions.

But without bashing on S.O. too much, I legitimately want to know if asking one more "bad" question on there would also ban me from ALL subsidiary QA sites (Pets, Physics, Ask Ubuntu, etc.)?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/ maybe more appropriate. Your question isn't specific to Ubuntu or even to Ask Ubuntu's meta site.

Comment: Short answer: no, automated question bans are site-specific

Comment: The fact that you post this question here shows pretty much why you are on the edge to get banned. Participating in a community requires to follow certain rules. The rules what is on-topic on AskUbuntu are written down [here](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic). If you want to get help from others, you have to be respectful and obey certain rules. If you post questions that are not on topic, or put very low effort into formatting, grammar and so on, then it is very disrespectful. Keep in mind that others will have to spend their free time in order to help you.

Comment: @muru I think you have enough characters there ;)

Comment: @Zanna true, but I'd rather OP got some help from SO people to start fixing things there, instead of encouragement to start posting SO questions here.

Comment: Fair enough. Still, while I get the impression SO is a tougher crowd, there's nothing *stopping* one getting a question ban on more than one site if one makes the same mistakes!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please see [Why are questions no longer being accepted from my account?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) from the Stack Overflow help center (or the equivalent page of any other SE network site) for more general information about question bans, how they work and what you can do to avoid them.

TL;DR: Post well received questions and also edit and improve your old questions to make them meet the respective site's standards of what makes a good and on-topic question. Consult the help center of each site, e.g. for [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/help) or [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help) section. Pay attention especially to the pinned entries, those are most important.

If, after reading those resources and revisiting your own posts, you still don't understand why they were badly received, you may consider asking on the respective Meta site about what is wrong with those posts, i.e. [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com) for your SO posts. Do your own research first and explain what you tried though, else that question would just get downvoted and ignored again.

Regarding your question whether a ban from asking or answering extends over multiple sites from the network, no, it does not, or at least I could not find any indication that it does.

All question and answer bans are also handled fully automatic by an algorithm that takes your contributions on a site and how well it was received into account. Moderators can neither manually impose or lift those.

Comment: Question bans won't apply across all sites, but if you are hitting against quality issues in SO chances are posts here are going to be hitting against similar question bans for the same mistakes - so start by hunting down the details about WHY your posts are being ill-received over on SO.